# how to compare lists and group them into a new list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration, max

if i have list like this:

```
array([[0.49487109, 0.50512891],
       [0.48823107, 0.51176893],
       [0.50411555, 0.49588445],
       [0.49592661, 0.50407339],
       [0.50394806, 0.49605194]])
```

and the result i want if maximum value in the array at right group in 1 array, and if the other part in the other group.
so the result is can look like this:

```
array([[0.49487109, 0.50512891],
       [0.48823107, 0.51176893],
       [0.49592661, 0.50407339]])
array([[0.50411555, 0.49588445],
       [0.50394806, 0.49605194]])
```

so, what should i do?

Comment: ehee, sorry, its "maximum value"

Comment: What is `array`? Are you using Numpy, or something else? And what exactly is the rule here? You want one output that has the array rows where the left column exceeds the right column, and another output with the other rows? Or what?

Comment: yeah, that using numpy. the rule is like what you tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val = [[0.49487109, 0.50512891],
       [0.48823107, 0.51176893],
       [0.50411555, 0.49588445],
       [0.49592661, 0.50407339],
       [0.50394806, 0.49605194]]

minmax = []
maxmin = []

for i in val:
    if i[0] < i[1]:
        minmax.append(i)
    else:
        maxmin.append(i)

print(minmax, maxmin)
```